# Query for Power BI Output from Azure Stream Analytics with JSON data

Tags: json, azure, stream, powerbi, analytics

I'm having an issue extracting data from IOT Hub to Azure Stream Analytics to Power BI.

Here is the data coming from Stream Analytics:

```
{  
   "header":{  
      "version":1
   },
   "data":{  
      "treatmentId":"1",
      "machineData":[  
         {  
            "recordId":3,
            "records":[  
               {  
                  "fields":[  
                     {  
                        "value":"+182",
                        "key":"VP"
                     }
                  ],
                  "group":"PR"
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   },
   "EventProcessedUtcTime":"2018-12-05T16:52:43.6450807Z",
   "PartitionId":0,
   "EventEnqueuedUtcTime":"2018-12-05T16:38:47.1900000Z",
   "IoTHub":{  
      "CorrelationId":null

   }
}
```

Using the following query:

```
SELECT * 
INTO DataPowerBI
FROM iothub;
```

I am getting the following output in PowerBI:

[image]

I am not able to get the child level data under "data", like treatment id, machine data, groups, keys. Can I get a query for pushing all levels of the data, both parent and children?

Thanks in advance!
Raj

Answer (score 1):

By using select *, you only get the upper level data-fields back. If you want the data that is nested, you need to specify the data you want.

select data.treatmentid will get you the treatmentId

I am not sure how it works with nesting within nesting. You could try 
select data.machinedata.recordId to get the recordId.